# stream_context_create bind to host / subdomain?

Tags: php, subdomain

I am using [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to bind php to an ip address already, but I would also like to bind it to a subdomain / host as well. Here is my code, which is working ...

The `$host` variable is to an mx record to a partner company's server, they want me to connect to it with a certain ip on my server, which works, but also want it to verify the subdomain as well.

```
$socket_options = array('socket' => array('bindto' => $this->ipaddress . ':0'));
$socket_context = stream_context_create($socket_options);
$this->smtp_conn = stream_socket_client($host . ':' . $port, $errno,
$errstr, $tval, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $socket_context);
```

I tried adding this to the $socket_options, but no luck - where `$this->Host` is my subdomain.

```
'http' => array('header' => "Host: " . $this->Host)
```

Is this even possible? I never heard of this being done before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot achieve this with the `bindto` option.

I would use a PKI authentication using sub-domain SSL certificates. See http://php-security.net/archives/3-X.509-PKI-login-with-PHP-and-Apache.html

Comment: I was hoping to not use ssl if possible, this was just their first use of this model and eventually wanted me to use a few different subdomains, and then have their clients do the same and the cost of a cert was something they want to avoid. I know its not a web page I am connecting to, but would header like the above work? I know that works when trying to connect to a page like a browser does. Or maybe even just the full domain could work, it seems when looking at the headers of the email sent with this that it doesn't show that either: Received: from domain.com (unknown [xxx.31.xx.10])

Comment: Just to clearify too, the domain.com was from the HELO message, the part I am trying to get to work is the part that says unknown, which in a normal email would be the host / subdomain. Thanks for any info you may have guys.

Comment: Ok I'm guessing there isn't much else possible with this, but please if anyone else has anything else to add please do so. I'll accept the answer above for the effort and the answer is correct, was hoping there might be another possible approach. Any other info, could lead me to other work arounds or possiblities so any info will still be useful and appreciated. Thanks Luno.

Comment: The PHP documentation says relatively enough about `stream_context_create` but it is not clear to me what problem are you trying to solve and thus whether binding a stream context to an IP address is going to solve it. Be more specific.